# How to assign component name during run-time?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hej,

In the Below code, I've assigned StaticMeshComponent name as "StaticMeshComponentCOMP1, StaticMeshComponentCOMP2". It is not very efficient for N component.

```
for (int32 i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  StaticMeshComponent[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponentCOMP1"));
  StaticMeshComponent[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponentCOMP2"));
// more code here
    }
```

So I've tried to assign StaticMeshComponent name as StaticMeshComponentCOMP with 'i'  as below, but couldn't able to achieve the result.

```
for (int32 i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     StaticMeshComponent[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponentCOMP" + '%i'));
}
```

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Edited for more understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your name as a separate FString variable. FString then has several append-functions, e.g. AppendInt().

```
FString name = FString(TEXT("StaticMeshComponentCOMP"));
name.AppendChar('-');
name.AppendInt(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, CreateDefaultSubobject( FName SubobjectFName), AppendInt() function not available for FName. Is there any another approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, I've solved the issue by converting FString to FName using FName temp = FName(*name);